# Sylius theming and multilanguage

Tags: sylius

im new to sylius and wanted to know does sylius have theming and multilanguage? I cant find multilanguage option anywhere only language selection. And themes should be awesome feature still cant find that. Thank for reply.

Answer (score 2):

Now Sylius is having theming facilities:

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusThemeBundle/index.html

***Short explanation:***

Themes reside in the 'app/themes/' folder (you can have multiple folders with different themes). The only required part for setting the theme is a composer file within the folder (each respective folders) and just add the name parameter. eg.

```
{
  "name": "theme-name"
}
```

for having a grouping of themes you can also have the name like 'group-name/theme-name'.

You need to activate your theme in your config file. For that, just add

```
sylius_theme:
    sources:
        filesystem: ~
```

Now when you are in the administrative panel at the backend, you can select this theme from the dropdown list while customising a 'Channel'.

You can also override any bundle and customise it. For details please check the documentation.

Comment: The link that you're posting could possibly be dead in the future. A more detailed explanation on the page would be better.

Comment: This is the official link and I think if the link is dead, then they don't use this bundle anymore or they have an alternative. But you can always search for the 'Sylius Theme Bundle' on internet. It is actually a bit huge to explain. But I will try to point out the focusing areas. I am explaining it in my original comment. @JonathanEustace

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.13 it now is fully i18n. You can even add translatable entities using the ResourceBundle.

Comment: The CMS side of Sylius is in a quite early stage. I'm working on an improved version based on Backbee but it won't be ready until a few months.